# delete entity in jpa in play framework

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have simply code:

```
    TypedQuery<Table> q = Table.em().createQuery(
            "select w from Table w ", Table.class);
    List<Table> toBeDeleted = q.getResultList();
    for (Table w : toBeDeleted) {
        w.delete();
    }
```

but I get error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance
>   models.Table

What is wrong?

Comment: Is the call to `Table.delete()` wrapped in a transaction?

Comment: @crizzis No, it should be ?

Comment: The entire method that queries the `Table` entities and then deletes them should be wrapped in a transaction. Otherwise, The entities retrieved from the query become detached immediately after query execution. As pointed out in the exception, removing a detached entity is illegal in JPA

Comment: @Crizzis Thanks for response, Can I do it without transactions ? Example with Table.em().merge(w) on each object before delete ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. `EntityManager.merge()` must be invoked in the context of a transaction here (calling it outside a transaction makes little sense in your case, as the entity would become detached immediately after the call as well).